# Pylab: Cannot Import Name Pcolor

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, scipy, pip

I get this error when I try to do this in python2.7:

```
>>>from pylab import pcolor
ImportError: cannot import name pcolor
```

Under pip freeze:

```
pylab==0.1.3
```

I've tried

```
pip install --upgrade pylab
```

to no avail. Anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score -2):

Fixed it. Had to uninstall matplotlib and reinstall

```
$ pip uninstall matplotlib
$ pip install matplotlib
```